# inputTextarea inside modalPanel does not update backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have this inputTextarea inside a modalPanel, and the only way I got to update the respective value (motivePopupMotive) in the backing bean is by adding an a4j:support in the inputTextarea just to set ajaxSingle=true, like this:

```
<a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"></a4j:support>
```

before calling the method save by clicking the button "btnSavePopupMotive". If I don't do this, the value in the backing bean, when I click the "btnSavePopupMotive" button is allways an empty string.

But I don't want this solution, because when I call ajax functions I show a "loading" image, and I don't want this image showing up just because the user enter some text in this input. How could I solve this? Here is the code:

```
<div style="position: absolute;">
    <a4j:form id="form2">
        <r:modalPanel id="panelPopupMotive" resizeable="false" autosized="true" minWidth="300" minHeight="20" >

            <table width="99%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px solid #000000;">
                <tr><td>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="fmeSmallLegend"><h:outputText value="Motive" /> </legend>
                            <table><tr><td>
                                <h:inputTextarea id="motivePopupMotive" 
                                    onkeydown="verifySize(this, 200);" 
                                    onkeyup="verifySize(this, 200);"
                                    onchange="verifySize(this, 200);"
                                    value="#{ParameterFaces.motivePopupMotive}"
                                    rows="4" style="width: 380px;" onfocus="this.style.background='#FFFED2';" onblur="this.style.background='#F5F5F5';">
                                </h:inputTextarea>                                          
                            </td></tr></table>
                        </fieldset>
                </td></tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a4j:commandButton id="btnSavePopupMotive"
                            value="Save" onclick="saveMotive();"
                            style="width:80px" type="submit"
                            oncomplete="closePopupMotive();"
                            title="Save" reRender="motivePopupMotive,existsErrorMotive">
                        </a4j:commandButton>
                        <r:spacer width="5px" />
                        <a4j:commandButton id="btnCancel"
                            value="Cancel" style="width:80px" 
                            oncomplete="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('panelPopupMotive');"
                            title="Cancel">
                        </a4j:commandButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>               
            </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function closePopupMotive(){
                    if (document.getElementById('form2:motivePopupMotive').value == 'false'){
                        Richfaces.hideModalPanel('panelPopupMotive');
                    }
                }
            </script>

            <a4j:jsFunction name="saveMotive" reRender="motivePopupMotive" oncomplete="saveValidatedMotive();"/>

            <a4j:jsFunction name="saveValidatedMotive" actionListener="#{ParameterFaces.save}" reRender=""/>
        </r:modalPanel>
    </a4j:form>
</div>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was using the modalPanel inside the form... I put the form outside the modalPanel and everything worked fine.